# Permutation character : what does it mean? and What is free multiplicity ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I knew a little about representation theory,

so,

Permutation character: what does it mean?

and what is free multiplicity?

Comment: A permutation character is the character of a permutation representation.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: yes I am here .

Comment: OK. Do you have anything to say?

Comment: Do you have any reference for that? I need more examples, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "examples"? Examples of what? Do you know what a permutation representation is? Do you know what a character of a representation is? Anyway, Chapters 7 and 8 of http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/notes/third_groups.html might help you.

Comment: I am not sure to say I know permutation representation very well. I looked at definitions for that but still can not understand it perfect.

Comment: OK – do you know what a representation is?

Comment: I took $G=S_3$ acts on set $X=\{1,2,3\}$ by taking the pair $(f,x)$ to $f(x)$ for all $f\in S_3$ and $x\in X$. let $h:X\longrightarrow X$ such that $h(x)=f(x)$  for all $x\in X$. So $h\in sym(X)$. Then the perumtation represntation of $S_3$ on $X$  is the homomorphism from $S_3\longrightarrow sym(X)$ ; $g\longrightarrow h$

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful, thanks a lot.